# How do I get exog= to work with ARMA/ARIMA?

Tags: python, time-series

> indexed_prime

Date                    Rev             Base      ARMadj  GSPrice
Date
2014-11-29 2014-11-29  124052.979500   516891.200 -8100.0     60.0
2014-12-06 2014-12-06   74197.122760  1033782.400 -9260.0     60.0
2014-12-13 2014-12-13   65113.157960  1550673.600 -7300.0     60.0
2014-12-20 2014-12-20   62540.688660  2067564.800 -8100.0     60.0
2014-12-27 2014-12-27   27166.139050  2089491.810 -9260.0     60.0
2015-01-03 2015-01-03   39491.384120  2111418.820 -7300.0     60.0
2015-01-10 2015-01-10   24158.035070  2133345.830 -4240.0     60.0
2015-01-17 2015-01-17   26423.724870  2155272.840 -1460.0     60.0
2015-01-24 2015-01-24   23256.475760  2161877.480   372.0     60.0
2015-01-31 2015-01-31   17122.817350  2168482.120  1190.0     60.0
2015-02-07 2015-02-07   23105.257360  2175086.760  1250.0     60.0
2015-02-14 2015-02-14   28942.415480  2181691.400   876.0     60.0
2015-02-21 2015-02-21   24446.400630  2184149.968   388.0     60.0
2015-02-28 2015-02-28   15850.090840  2186608.536   -24.3     60.0
2015-03-07 2015-03-07   15591.600440  2189067.104  -280.0     60.0
2015-03-14 2015-03-14   24523.027370  2191525.672  -381.0     60.0
2015-03-21 2015-03-21   32004.347500  2193984.240  -371.0     60.0
2015-03-28 2015-03-28   27826.800740  2197643.770  -305.0     60.0
2015-04-04 2015-04-04   20206.361870  2201303.300  -228.0     60.0
2015-04-11 2015-04-11   19141.036990  2204962.830  -168.0     60.0
2015-04-18 2015-04-18   22040.487130  2208622.360  -133.0     60.0
2015-04-25 2015-04-25   24693.562020  2211230.140  -121.0     60.0
2015-05-02 2015-05-02   25908.055260  2213837.920  -125.0     60.0

> print (indexed.prime.dtypes)
>   Date                      datetime64[ns]
>   Seasadjrev                       float64
>   Base                             float64
>   ARMadj                           float64
>   GSPrice                          float64

indexed_prime3 = indexed_prime.drop('Rev', axis=1)
    import numpy as np
    from scipy import stats
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import statsmodels.api as sm
    from pandas.tools.plotting import autocorrelation_plot
    arma_mod22 = sm.tsa.ARMA(indexed_df['Rev'], order=(2,2) exog=indexed_prime3) nets:

File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\arima_model.py", line 445, in **init**
    super(ARMA, self).**init**(endog, exog, dates, freq, missing=missing)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\base\tsa_model.py", line 41, in **init**
    super(TimeSeriesModel, self).**init**(endog, exog, missing=missing)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py", line 186, in **init**
    super(LikelihoodModel, self).**init**(endog, exog, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py", line 60, in **init**
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py", line 84, in _handle_data
    data = handle_data(endog, exog, missing, hasconst, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\data.py", line 566, in handle_data
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\data.py", line 72, in **init**
    self.endog, self.exog = self._convert_endog_exog(endog, exog)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\data.py", line 428, in _convert_endog_exog
    raise ValueError("Pandas data cast to numpy dtype of object. "
ValueError: Pandas data cast to numpy dtype of object. Check input data with np.asarray(data).

> > >

I can't figure out how to bring in exogenous variables into the model - can someone help?

Comment: Based on the ValueError on the last line your exog variable `indexed_prime3` is not something that can be converted to float. Why do you include "Date" among the `exog` regressors? Either drop or convert. It is safest to include only float64 variables.

Comment: Everything is float64 except the indexed date I avoided having this before but I got another error that it wasn't indexed

Comment: Your "Date" looks like a regular column and not an index. Try `np.asarray(indexed_prime3)` or `np.asarray(your_exog)` and make sure it is float64. According to your exception it is an object array. (I think the exception message should be pretty obvious.)